# UIImagePickerController selects the wrong picture (or crashes) in iOS7 after deleting image

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios7

I have an app that uses a UIImagePickerController to allow a user to select a profile picture. I've noticed a bug in iOS7 where it selects the incorrect image if you delete an image from your photo stream while the UIImagePickerController is active.

To observe this bug in action you can use the Facebook app or any app which uses a UIImagePickerController such as the Twitter app.

Open Facebook iOS app --> tap profile pic --> tap "choose existing" --> minimize Facebook app --> open the Photos app --> delete some photos from the start of the photo stream --> go back to Facebook iOS app --> try selecting a photo --> the selected photo is NOT the photo that was tapped (or, if you tap the last image, the app crashes, presumably due to an array index out of bounds error).

It seems as though in iOS7 the UIImagePickerController doesn't refresh the photo stream when the app comes into the foreground. Obviously this bug could cause some serious user experience problems.

Hopefully Apple puts through a fix to this bug ASAP, but in the meantime I was wondering if anyone has any workarounds to this bug? The last thing I want is someone using my app to accidentally upload a photo that they would never want seen on the Internet.

Comment: Yikes, that's bad. Did you file a radar?

Comment: Yeah, very bad + it's probably an easy fix. Submitted an Apple bug report with Twitter and Facebook iOS crash logs as examples. (Plus, for good measure, submitted bug reports to Facebook and Twitter.)